# Как создать ряд форм в PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qlayout, qlabel

Имеется код, который создает форму, совмещающую в себе свойство кнопки (при клике выполняется функция) и одновременно можно выполнять изменение текста внутри.

Возникает проблема расстановки множества таких форм, можно конечно создать несколько переменных и выполнять одни и те же действия с ними, но это много одного и того же повторяющегося кода.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ расстановки нескольких форм сразу без повторяющегося кода.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    doubleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.setText("Hello World")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.doubleClicked.emit()


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setObjectName('test')

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)).name()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.label.doubleClicked.connect(self.onDoubleClicked)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editFinished)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(self.label.geometry())
        self.lineEdit.hide()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)).name()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")

    def onDoubleClicked(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.label.text())
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")
        self.lineEdit.show()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def editFinished(self):
        self.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.lineEdit.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Примерное фото множества таких форм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    doubleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.setText("Hello World")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.doubleClicked.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):                                            # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)
        
        self.label = Label(self)          
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)).name()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.label.doubleClicked.connect(self.onDoubleClicked)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)          
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editFinished)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(self.label.geometry())
        self.lineEdit.hide()        

    def onClicked(self):
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)).name()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")

    def onDoubleClicked(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.label.text())
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {self.color}")
        self.lineEdit.show()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def editFinished(self):
        self.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.lineEdit.hide()
        

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setObjectName('test')
        
        widget = Widget()                                                    # +++

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Widget")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.onClickButton)
        
        self.row, self.column = 0, 0
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(widget, self.row, self.column) 
        self.grid.addWidget(btn, 10, 0, 1, 4) 

    def onClickButton(self):
        self.column += 1
        widget = Widget()                                                    # +++
        self.grid.addWidget(widget, self.row, self.column)

        if self.column == 3:
            self.column = -1
            self.row += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! А можно Вам задать еще пару личных вопросов? Если нет, то можете не отвечать.
1) Где Вы работаете? 0-0
2) Сколько Вам лет?

Comment: @GunTHE Я - свободный художник. Каждому взрослому человеку в среднем пятнадцать с половиной лет (Йонас Фрисен).